# FIORI: display PDF file sent from the Gateway

Tags: sapui5

I'm working on this Fiori app (both ABAP and UI5 parts). I have to send a PDF file from the back-end server to the Fiori app and then display it in a new tab whenever the user pushes a button.

I have no idea how to implement this. Searching on the internet, I found examples that explains the ABAP part but not the Fiori part (and conversely ).

Does any one please have a full example implementing this scenario ?
Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 2):

```
<Button press="openPDF" text="Open PDF"></Button>

openPDF : function(){
        var URL = "https://www.sapfioritrial.com/sap/opu/odata/sap/HCM_MY_PAYSTUBS_SRV/PDFPaystubs(SEQUENCENUMBER=1694,PersonnelAssignment='00100226')/$value";
        sap.m.URLHelper.redirect( URL, true )
        }
```

The example from SAP demokit can help you

[PDF Viewer](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/entity/sap.m.PDFViewer)

Comment: Thanks for your response. Unfortunatly, I cannot use the PDFViewer since I am using the 1.38 UI5 version (PDFViewer  is available since: 1.48)

Answer (score 0):

There is a dedicated control for it and is part of the UI5 library. The control is: PDFViewer. You can read more in here: https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.m.PDFViewer/overview

I found also some blog which explain how to do it with smart forms that may help you.

https://blogs.sap.com/2014/04/23/sapui5-pdf-viewer-smartforms-custom-control/

Comment: Thanks for your response. Unfortunatly, I cannot use the PDFViewer since I am using the 1.38 UI5 version (PDFViewer  is available since: 1.48)

Comment: And you cannot upgrade it to 1.48 ?