# How can I generate a PDF file using oData Api A_BillingDocument in FIORI web ide using getPDF

Tags: pdf-generation, sapui5, sap-fiori

I am able to get 200 response in Postman when I do a get request using following URL.
https://my######-api.s4hana.ondemand.com/sap/opu/odata/sap/API_BILLING_DOCUMENT_SRV/GetPDF?BillingDocument='90000011'

I get BillingDocumentBinary as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<d:GetPDF m:type="API_BILLING_DOCUMENT_SRV.GetPDFResult" xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices" xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata">
    <d:BillingDocumentBinary>JVBERi0xLjYNJeLjz9MNCjE2MiAwIG9iago8PC9GaWx0ZXIvRmxhdGVEZWNvZGUvRmlyc3QgMTA2....
..
CDAAXvQZzQplbmRzdHJlYW0KZW5kb2JqCnN0YXJ0eHJlZgoyNDg1OAolJUVPRgo=</d:BillingDocumentBinary>
</d:GetPDF>
```

I would like to create fiori app and display invoices in pdf format. Is is possible? I am currently using this API to search and display invoices using fiori and it appears to be working. But I have no idea if we can display pDF using this getPDF. I would appreciate if someone has gone this road and willing to share some light.

Comment: There is a UI5 control sap.m.PDFViewer, which might solve your problem.
Please see the official docu here: https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.m.PDFViewer
and some samples here: https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/entity/sap.m.PDFViewer

Comment: There are also a few blogs and one stackoverflow question that might also be helpful: [FIORI: display PDF file sent from the Gateway](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48586048/fiori-display-pdf-file-sent-from-the-gateway), [Display PDF in SAP UI5](https://blogs.sap.com/2018/08/24/display-pdf-in-sap-ui5/), 
[SAPUI5 PDF Viewer – UI5Lab](https://blogs.sap.com/2018/06/14/sapui5-pdf-viewer-ui5lab/), and [PDF Download Option with SAPUI5](https://blogs.sap.com/2016/11/23/pdf-download-option-with-sapui5/)

Comment: PDF Viewer will not help me. I don't have a PDF that is already out for me to display it. I am currently pursuing CPI route using open connectors to see if this helps. [link] https://blogs.sap.com/2018/09/25/part-6-simplify-integration-of-data-from-sap-to-third-party-applications/